# Retrieving the 3DES decryption key from plaintext and ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, keys, 3des

I have a hex key that I want to decrypt with a 3DES key in mode ECB.

For example:

```
hex-key : 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef

3DES key: fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210

result  : c89bc7b07189ed94c89bc7b07189ed94
```

How can I find the 3ES encryption/decryption key from the two entries `hex-key` and `result`?

Comment: So you want to find a 3DES key being only given a single valid plaintext-ciphertext pair (ie one $P$ and one $C$ such that $C=E_K(P)$ for some searched-for key $K$)?

Comment: My interpretation of his question: he has a 128 bit 3DES key in hex ("hexkey"), and want to know how to get the 3DES key...

Comment: thanks for reply , all my keys are 16 bytes . than how to calculate the 3des from the hex key and result ?

Comment: I'm sorry to point out something that (to me) seems to be incredibly obvious, but isn't the value you listed as `hexkey` the 3DES key you're looking for?

Comment: thanks poncho to reply but the 3des is known now fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210 i search how to calculat this value if i have juste the plaintext 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef and the result c89bc7b07189ed94c89bc7b07189ed94 thanks to help

Comment: @rabie, it looks like you might have somehow ended up with multiple accounts. For help on how to have them merged, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: So what you called *hex-key* is actually the plaintext and *result* is the ciphertext you get when you encrypt *plaintext/hex-key* using 3DES with the key *3DES key*. Is that correct. And your question is, if it possible to recalculate *3DES key* if all you know is *plaintext/hex-key* and *ciphertext/result*?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to find a 3DES key from a known plaintext / ciphertext pair (it increasingly looks that this is what you're asking). If that was the case then 3DES would either have to be:

1. vulnerable with regard to the key size or;
2. vulnerable against attacks that invalidate the cipher.

Now although two key triple DES shouldn't be used anymore, it still has a *minimum* security of around 80 bits (for attacks that are not even applicable in your single plaintext / ciphertext situation).

And, as indicated by the text above, it has certainly not been broken in a sense that you can (easily) recalculate the key. Allowing an attacker to find the full key is as broken as a cipher can get; in general it is assumed that an attacker knows parts of the plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it!

When [3DES keying option 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) with the 16-byte *"3DES key"* `fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210`
 is used in [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) to decipher the 16-byte *"hex-key"* `0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef` (2 blocks), the result is the 16-byte *"result"* `c89bc7b07189ed94c89bc7b07189ed94`.